# Add Text at top of exported CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to create a csv file with objectid of computers in AzureAD to be able to import into a group.
The format of the csv need to be:

```
version:v1.0
[memberObjectIdOrUpn]
```

then a list of objectid of the computers

```
$devices = Get-AzureADDevice -SearchString COMPUTERS
$devices = $devices.objectid | Select-Object @{n = '[memberObjectIdOrUpn]'; e = { $_ } }
$devices | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\computers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

this will get me a list with the only issue that "version:v1.0" needs to be added on top of the file.

Is there some way to add it before exporting the csv or do I need to do like:

```
@("version:v1.0") +  (Get-Content "C:\temp\computers.csv") | Set-Content "c:\temp\computers.csv"
```

I just feel like there's some better way :)

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine (regardless of how you feel) :)

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with this approach imo.

Comment: there is a `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet to give you all the text that would be in an export-to-csv file. so you can build that, concatenate it with your custom prefix line[s], and then send that to a file. [*grin*]

Comment: I forgot about ConvertTo-Csv !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `Convert-Csv` might be easier, as it returns a string array rather than writing a file.

```
# get the system line separator for convenientce
$newline = [Environment]::NewLine

# set up the file header
$header = ("version:v1.0{0}" -f $newline) 

# get the device list (returns an array of strings)
$devices = Get-AzureADDevice -SearchString COMPUTERS
$devices = $devices.objectid | Select-Object @{n = '[memberObjectIdOrUpn]'; e = { $_ } } | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation 

# write the header and your content
Set-Content -Value ($headers + ($devices -join $newline)) -Path C:\temp\computers.csv
```